# How to print a matrix in an R plot?

Tags: r, matrix, plot

..Not how to plot a matrix.
I want to insert a 3x3 matrix into an R-plot, I don't see how to do this within plotmath() which mimics alot of latex commands.
I would like to mimic the latex pmatrix environment style.
This trick works for 2x2 matrices:

> text(1,.4, expression(bgroup("(", atop("x 4 f", "y 3 5"), ")")))

Comment: I was really disappointed when support for the tikz-device languished. It allowed real LaTex. There is a `latex` driver in Hmisc.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
text(1,.4, expression(bgroup("(", atop("x 4 f", atop("y 3 5","z 2 k")), ")")))
```

You could also try an approach like this to have all the rows be the same size font:

```
text(1,.4, expression(bgroup("(", atop("\n",paste("x 4 f \ny 3 5 \nz 2 k")), ")")),cex=0.8)
```

or

```
text(1,.4, expression(bgroup("(", atop("\n",paste(" x 4 f \n y 3 5 \n z 2 k")), ")")),cex=0.8)
```

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that too. Problem is the first row is larger than the two bottom rows..

Comment: @user1666237 That's true.  See my edit for an alternate solution.  Just an fyi, in order to make your questions more complete, you should show what you have already tried.

Comment: text(5,5, expression(bgroup("(", atop(" \n",paste(" x 4 f \n y 3 5 \n z 2 k")), ")")),cex=0.6) is almost perfect. Thanks ur answer and advice.